# Error al llamar un método desde otra clase

Tags: java, android

Estoy tratando de llamar un método desde otra clase con el fin de actualizar el globo flotante de mi icono de carrito.

El código de `MenuActivity` es el siguiente y funciona perfectamente:

```
public void contadorcarrito() {

    final ArrayList<String> cont= new ArrayList<String>();

    cont.clear();

    PedidosExpressApp app = (PedidosExpressApp) getApplicationContext();
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    String url = app.getConexion()+"contador.php";

    RequestParams parametros = new RequestParams();
    parametros.put("idusuario", app.getId());

    RequestHandle post = client.post(url, parametros, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new String(responseBody));

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        cont.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("contador"));
                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"SI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                PedidosExpressApp app = (PedidosExpressApp) getApplicationContext();
                app.setContador_icono(Integer.parseInt(cont.get(0)));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contador Pedidos= "+ cont.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                setupBadge();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error de Conexion intente mas tarde", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}

public void setupBadge() {

    PedidosExpressApp app = (PedidosExpressApp) getApplicationContext();
    int contador_cart = app.getContador_icono();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pedidos "+ contador_cart, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (contador_icon != null) {
        if (contador_cart == 0) {
            if (contador_icon.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
                contador_icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } else {
            contador_icon.setText(String.valueOf(Math.min(contador_cart, 99)));
            if (contador_icon.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                contador_icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                contadorcarrito();
            }
        }, DURACION_RECARGAR_CARRITO);
    }else {
        contador_icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                contadorcarrito();
            }
        }, DURACION_RECARGAR_CARRITO);
    }
}
```

Ahora necesito llamar el método `contadorcarrito()` desde la clase Carrito.class con el siguiente código:

```
    MenuActivity menuActivity = new MenuActivity();
    menuActivity.contadorcarrito();
```

El código me arroja el siguiente error:

```
    07-26 13:08:57.316 19225-19225/com.example.jarenas.pedidosexpress E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    Process: com.example.jarenas.pedidosexpress, PID: 19225
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:107)
        at com.example.jarenas.pedidosexpress.MenuActivity.contadorcarrito(MenuActivity.java:224)
        at com.example.jarenas.pedidosexpress.CarritoActivity.onSupportNavigateUp(CarritoActivity.java:321)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:202)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:113)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper$1.onClick(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:187)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Que hace referencia a esta línea de `MenuActivity`:

```
     PedidosExpressApp app = (PedidosExpressApp) getApplicationContext();
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar ese error?

Comment: Prueba a llamar a ese método (getApplicationContext()) en la case Carrito y pasársela por parámetro al método contadorcarrito(cont).

Comment: @Jahir que es la clase PedidosExpressApp , podrías agregarla

Answer (score 0):

Pudiera trabajar con la libreria EventBus https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus que te la recomiendo para este tipo de situaciones que requiere hacer cambios a otras clases desde otras clases, es para manejo de eventos, o trabajarlo con startActivityForResult si te es posible una vez para hacer los cambios una vez hayas cerrado la nueva actividad que creaste.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes inicializar una Actividad creando una instancia manualmente porque no le estas asignando el context con el que va a trabajar y por lo tanto te lanza `NullPointerException`. Los `Activity`s deben de inicializarse con `startActivity` utilizando un `Intent` que es el objeto que le pasa el `Context` a las `Activity`s. .

Dicho eso, lo que puedes hacer es enviarle el `Context` como parametro al metodo:

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity
{

   public void contadorcarrito(Context _context) 
   {

        final ArrayList<String> cont= new ArrayList<String>();
        cont.clear();

        PedidosExpressApp app = (PedidosExpressApp)_context.getApplicationContext();

        //...
   }
}
```

Uso*:

```
MenuActivity menuActivity= new MenuActivity();
menuActivity.contadorcarrito(Carrito.this);
```

Si lo unico que la clase `MenuActivity` hace  es hacer peticiones http y nada relacionado con una vista, entonces no deberias de extender de `Activity`

<sub>* Se entiende que la clase `Carrito` extiende de Activity, sino entonces pasale un contexto de un `Activity` Activo.</sub>

Comment: getApplicationContext() se puede llamar sin problema dentro de una Activity.

Comment: Aun si fue inicializada manualmente sin el `Intent`? No tengo un android studio disponible actualmente para probarlo y la doc no dice nada al respecto. Pudieras confirmarme eso? Me interesa saber eso @Jorgesys

Answer (score 0):

El erro que presentas es que el contexto esta null, eso es por que quieres presentar elgo de una vista que esta en otra vista o hace referencia a otra vista
para solucionarlo solo agrega el contexto a tu metodo carrito
public void contadorcarrito(Context contexto)
para que tu clace carrito reciva el contexto como parametro

ahora cuando llames al metodo carrito desde tu activity

```
contadorcarrito() // enves de esto pasale lo siguiente
contadorcarrito(getAplicationContext)
```

y listo con eso tu clace carrito sabra en que contexto aplicar las funciones